# Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, format-conversion

How would you convert from XML to JSON and then back to XML?

The following tools work quite well, but aren't completely consistent:

- [xml2json](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/)

Has anyone encountered this situation before?

Comment: Explain the inconsistencies, please

Comment: Specifically, had to do with converting JSON arrays with just 1 element to XML. When you converted it back to JSON, instead of a 1-element array, it created the object literal. I worked around it by checking the type with $.isArray(), and wrapping it in an array if !$.isArray().

Comment: xml2json - http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/ - breaks throws 500 as of 15/02/2013 14:25 AEST

Comment: The json2xml link is broken.

Comment: @ysrb The plugin example will not work in IE8!

Comment: https://github.com/javadev/xml-to-json I am the mainteiner of the library.

Comment: Have you try this?https://devtoolsonline20190908040816.azurewebsites.net/DevTools/Convert_JSON2XML

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I think this is the best one:  [Converting between XML and JSON](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/)

Be sure to read the [accompanying article on the xml.com O'Reilly site](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html), which goes into details of the problems with these conversions, which I think you will find enlightening.  The fact that O'Reilly is hosting the article should indicate that Stefan's solution has merit.

Comment: thanks for the reply! In my case, the JSON is the canonical representation, and XML is just used for XSLT.. the use of which is not my idea! :)

Comment: This is only in the browser. Doesn't apply for node.js or non-browser environments. Any other ideas?

Comment: In regards to @JasonDenizac comment to his post, I am not sure to understand how this link helps fixing the issue of having an object instead of an array of one item...

Comment: I found that if you start from json-xml-json, this library works well, but if you want xml-json-xml there is a problem with reversibility since it adds metadata xml elements like <o> and <e>

Comment: Please note that this is a copyleft licensed solution. It is only an option when you are writing open source software.

Comment: @Jasper: That isn't true re the LGPL. Straight from the gnu's mouth, as it were: https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/why-not-lgpl.html.  Using the LGPL is generally only a problem if you change the code and even then you only need to release your changes.

Comment: @0x1mason LGPL is tricky. Using a minifier (which is common for javascript) might be in breach of it (though you would need a lawyer to be sure). I was wrong to say you can't use it when not writing FOSS, but if you aren't, you will have to be careful not to step into the legal minefield that LGPL creates...

Comment: For me this alerts some "unhandled types" in Firefox v30 on Win7

Comment: It is Really the Best.

Comment: Is there a "Standard" tool. i dread downloading the best tool only to find two years later its been abandoned.

Comment: @Dan The tools xml2json and json2xml _have been_ abandoned for 13 years. But who cares? The scripts will continue to work. It is vanilla JS.

Answer (score 56):

https://github.com/abdmob/x2js - my own library (updated URL from http://code.google.com/p/x2js/):

> This library provides XML to JSON (JavaScript Objects) and vice versa javascript conversion functions. The library is very small and doesn't require any other additional libraries.
>
> API functions
>
> - new X2JS() - to create your instance to access all library functionality. Also you could specify optional configuration options here
> - X2JS.xml2json - Convert XML specified as DOM Object to JSON
> - X2JS.json2xml - Convert JSON to XML DOM Object
> - X2JS.xml_str2json - Convert XML specified as string to JSON
> - X2JS.json2xml_str - Convert JSON to XML string

Online Demo on http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gkxucxrj/1/

```
var x2js = new X2JS();
function convertXml2JSon() {
    $("#jsonArea").val(JSON.stringify(x2js.xml_str2json($("#xmlArea").val())));
}

function convertJSon2XML() {
    $("#xmlArea").val(x2js.json2xml_str($.parseJSON($("#jsonArea").val())));
}

convertXml2JSon();
convertJSon2XML();
$("#convertToJsonBtn").click(convertXml2JSon);
$("#convertToXmlBtn").click(convertJSon2XML);
```

Comment: Hi, how did you overcome the issue where if you have one object in an object it is in object litteral, where if there is n > 1 objects, you have an array. This makes it hard to use xml to json objects in templates...

Comment: Yes, you should use some trick and it depends on your knowledge about XML structure (because no XSD here). Use <node>...<node>_asArray syntax to access your node always as array(sequence)

Comment: Sample:// XML string to JSON    
    var xmlText = "<MyOperation><test>Success</test><test2><item>ddsfg</item><item>dsdgfdgfd</item></test2></MyOperation>";
    var jsonObj = X2JS.xml_str2json( xmlText );
    alert (jsonObj.MyOperation.test);
    alert (jsonObj.MyOperation.test_asArray[0]);

Comment: My main problem, is when I transform my json to xml back, the json is full of extra properties, and when the string xml version keeps all the useless stuff. It has all kind of commas, and whitespaces...

Comment: could you submit your sample to https://code.google.com/p/x2js/issues I'll check it

Comment: Is this your own library? If so, please add a note to your answer. It's good form.

Comment: Well done, I can easily parse an entire OData $metadata
Saved me days of refactor

Comment: @abdolence: you saved my time. thank you so much. it really worked.

Comment: @abdolence Is that repo still maintained? It looks kinda dead :-(

Comment: @Potherca I'm really sorry, x2js is really an old lib and I stopped using it personally many years ago. 
I saw a lot of forks though and think you can find something more updated for nowadays browsers/environments.

Answer (score 40):

These answers helped me a lot to make this function:

```js
function xml2json(xml) {
  try {
    var obj = {};
    if (xml.children.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < xml.children.length; i++) {
        var item = xml.children.item(i);
        var nodeName = item.nodeName;

        if (typeof (obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
          obj[nodeName] = xml2json(item);
        } else {
          if (typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
            var old = obj[nodeName];

            obj[nodeName] = [];
            obj[nodeName].push(old);
          }
          obj[nodeName].push(xml2json(item));
        }
      }
    } else {
      obj = xml.textContent;
    }
    return obj;
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

As long as you pass in a jquery dom/xml object: for me it was:

```js
Jquery(this).find('content').eq(0)[0]
```

where *content* was the field I was storing my xml in.

Comment: saved my day! Almost all other examples are not working even JSFiddle examples!

Comment: works pretty good so far. Thank you

Comment: ERROR: xml.children is undefined

Comment: Looks like you're not grabbing any element attributes, which is where almost all the data I need is stored.

Comment: I found this most useful among all the answers because it is easy to handle all kind of attribute usages of xml docs out there, at the last part of the code  "else { obj = xml.textContent; }".

Answer (score 21):

I've created a recursive function based on regex, in case you don't want to install library and understand the logic behind what's happening:

```js
const xmlSample = '<tag>tag content</tag><tag2>another content</tag2><tag3><insideTag>inside content</insideTag><emptyTag /></tag3>';
console.log(parseXmlToJson(xmlSample));

function parseXmlToJson(xml) {
    const json = {};
    for (const res of xml.matchAll(/(?:<(\w*)(?:\s[^>]*)*>)((?:(?!<\1).)*)(?:<\/\1>)|<(\w*)(?:\s*)*\/>/gm)) {
        const key = res[1] || res[3];
        const value = res[2] && parseXmlToJson(res[2]);
        json[key] = ((value && Object.keys(value).length) ? value : res[2]) || null;

    }
    return json;
}
```

Regex explanation for each loop:

- res[0] - return the xml (as is)
- res[1] - return the xml tag name
- res[2] - return the xml content
- res[3] - return the xml tag name in case the tag closes itself.  In example: `<tag />`

You can check how the regex works here:
https://regex101.com/r/ZJpCAL/1

Note: In case json has a key with an undefined value, it is being removed. 
That's why I've inserted null at the end of line 9.

Comment: Not working as expected deep nested xml string values.

Comment: @sankarmuniyappa please write an example that didn't work so I'll fix it :)

Comment: how to make it work with this XML? ```<chan>
<item>
<tag>tag content</tag><tag2>another content</tag2><tag3><insideTag>inside content</insideTag><emptyTag /></tag3>
</item>
<item>
<tag>tag content</tag><tag2>another content</tag2><tag3><insideTag>inside content</insideTag><emptyTag /></tag3>
</item>
</chan>```

Comment: The function returns the correct output for your case:
`{"chan":{"item":{"tag":"tag content","tag2":"another content","tag3":{"insideTag":"inside content","emptyTag":null}}}}`

Comment: @MasterPiece hmm, in https://docs.scriptable.app, the function only returns the last one item: ```{"tag":"tag2 content","tag2":"another content 2","tag3":{"insideTag":"inside content 2","emptyTag":null}}```

Comment: if I write <tag3>
      <insideTag>inside content</insideTag>
      <emptyTag />
      </tag3>  in multiple lines using Template Literals it does not return nested json instead It separates all keys.

Comment: If I use the same tag twice, it only gives the first tag and it's value.

Answer (score 5):

I was using xmlToJson just to get a single value of the xml.
I found doing the following is much easier (if the xml only occurs once..)

```js
let xml =
'<person>' +
  ' <id>762384324</id>' +
  ' <firstname>Hank</firstname> ' +
  ' <lastname>Stone</lastname>' +
'</person>';

let getXmlValue = function(str, key) {
  return str.substring(
    str.lastIndexOf('<' + key + '>') + ('<' + key + '>').length,
    str.lastIndexOf('</' + key + '>')
  );
}


alert(getXmlValue(xml, 'firstname')); // gives back Hank
```

Comment: Keep up the job! This definitely helped me!

Comment: No problem!!! BD

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [txml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/txml). It can parse into a DOM made of simple objects and stringify. In the result, the content will be trimmed. So formating of the original with whitespaces will be lost. But this could be used very good to minify HTML.

```
const xml = require('txml');
const data = `
<tag>tag content</tag>
<tag2>another content</tag2>
<tag3>
  <insideTag>inside content</insideTag>
  <emptyTag />
</tag3>`;

const dom = xml(data); // the dom can be JSON.stringified

xml.stringify(dom); // this will return the dom into an xml-string
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of [txml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/txml), the fastest xml parser in javascript.

Comment:  This is a great drop-in replacement for `fast-xml-parser`, using `simplify`, that doesn't convert strings to numbers arbitrarily (like `"1.0"` to `1` or `1.`)

Answer (score 3):

A while back I wrote this tool https://bitbucket.org/surenrao/xml2json for my TV Watchlist app, hope this helps too.

> Synopsys: A library to not only convert xml to json, but is also easy to debug (without circular errors) and recreate json back to xml. Features :- Parse xml to json object. Print json object back to xml. Can be used to save xml in IndexedDB as X2J objects. Print json object.

Comment: @kleopatra this link points to the tool which converts xml to json. Its not a reference but the actual link to the resource. Not sure how else i should do it :)

Answer (score 3):

In 6 simple ES6 lines:

```js
xml2json = xml => {                                                                                                                                                     
  var el = xml.nodeType === 9 ? xml.documentElement : xml                                                                                                               
  var h  = {name: el.nodeName}                                                                                                                                          
  h.content    = Array.from(el.childNodes || []).filter(e => e.nodeType === 3).map(e => e.textContent).join('').trim()                                                  
  h.attributes = Array.from(el.attributes || []).filter(a => a).reduce((h, a) => { h[a.name] = a.value; return h }, {})                                                 
  h.children   = Array.from(el.childNodes || []).filter(e => e.nodeType === 1).map(c => h[c.nodeName] = xml2json(c))                                                    
  return h                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Test with `echo "xml2json_example()" | node -r xml2json.es6` with source at https://github.com/brauliobo/biochemical-db/blob/master/lib/xml2json.es6

Comment: 6 simple lines, plus 2000 lines from `xml2json`

Comment: @ShortFuse the only dependency is xmldom, a xml parser. this doesn't use xml2json from npm, although the name is the same

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I've written [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser)

Fast XML Parser can help to convert XML to JSON and vice versa. Here is the example;

```
var options = {
    attributeNamePrefix : "@_",
    attrNodeName: "attr", //default is 'false'
    textNodeName : "#text",
    ignoreAttributes : true,
    ignoreNameSpace : false,
    allowBooleanAttributes : false,
    parseNodeValue : true,
    parseAttributeValue : false,
    trimValues: true,
    decodeHTMLchar: false,
    cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is 'false'
    cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
};
if(parser.validate(xmlData)=== true){//optional
    var jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlData,options);
}
```

If you want to parse JSON or JS object into XML then

```
//default options need not to set
var defaultOptions = {
    attributeNamePrefix : "@_",
    attrNodeName: "@", //default is false
    textNodeName : "#text",
    ignoreAttributes : true,
    encodeHTMLchar: false,
    cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is false
    cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
    format: false, 
    indentBy: "  ",
    supressEmptyNode: false
};
var parser = new parser.j2xParser(defaultOptions);
var xml = parser.parse(json_or_js_obj);
```

Comment: :D FXP is more than XML 2 JSON converter. Please check it's readme.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend [this tool](https://github.com/enkidootech/xml2json). It is an XML to JSON converter.

It is very lightweight and is in pure JavaScript. It needs no dependencies. You can simply add the functions to your code and use it as you wish.

It also takes the XML attributes into considerations.

```
var xml = ‘<person id=”1234” age=”30”><name>John Doe</name></person>’;
var json = xml2json(xml); 

console.log(json); 
// prints ‘{“person”: {“id”: “1234”, “age”: “30”, “name”: “John Doe”}}’
```

Here's an [online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/enkidootech/ogsousqd/18/)!

Comment: github repo not found

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#xml-builder-usage)' a good tool from a documented and very famous npm library that does the xml <-> js conversions very well: differently from some (maybe all) of the above proposed solutions, it converts xml comments also.

```
var obj = {name: "Super", Surname: "Man", age: 23};

var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open sourced library [Xml-to-json](https://github.com/javadev/xml-to-json) with methods jsonToXml(json) and xmlToJson(xml).

Here's an [online demo](https://xmltojson.github.io)!

Answer (score 0):

This function directly reads the DOM properties of the `XMLDocument` (or document node/element) to build the JSON completely and accurately without trying to guess or match.  Pass it `responseXML`, not `responseText` from `XMLHttpRequest`.

```js
xml2json(xmlDoc)
```

If you only have a string of XML and not an `XMLDocument`, jQuery will convert your text to one.

```js
xml2json($(xmlString)[0])
```

- Each node becomes an object. (All elements are nodes, not all nodes are elements (e.g. text within an element).)
- Every object contains the node `name` and `type`.
- If it has attributes, they appear as properties in an `attributes` object.
- If it has children, they appear recursively as node->objects in a `children` array.
- If it's a Text, CDATA, or Comment node (bare text between element tags) or a comment, it shouldn't have `attributes` or `children` but the text will be in a `text` property.

```json
{
  // Always present
  "name": "FancyElement",
  "type": "Element",

  // If present
  "attributes: {
    "attr1": "val1",
    "attr2": "val2"
  },
  "children": [...],
  "text": "buncha fancy words"
}
```

> Caveat: I'm not familiar with all the node types. It's probably not grabbing needed/useful info from all of them. It was tested on and behaves as expected for
>
> - Element
> - Text
> - CDATA
> - Comment
> - Document

```js
function xml2json(xml) {
  try {
    const types = [null,
      "Element",
      "Attribute",
      "Text",
      "CDATA",
      "EntityReference", // Deprecated
      "Entity", // Deprecated
      "ProcessingInstruction",
      "Comment",
      "Document",
      "DocumentType",
      "DocumentFragment",
      "Notation" // Deprecated
    ];

    var o = {};
    o.name = xml.nodeName;
    o.type = types[xml.nodeType];

    if (xml.nodeType == 3 ||
        xml.nodeType == 4 ||
        xml.nodeType == 8 ) {
      o.text = xml.textContent;
    } else {
      if (xml.attributes) {
        o.attributes = {};
        for (const a of xml.attributes) {
          o.attributes[a.name] = a.value;
        }
      }

      if (xml.childNodes.length) {
        o.children = [];
        for (const x of xml.childNodes) {
          o.children.push(xml2json(x))
        }
      }
    }
    return (o);
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Error in xml2json. See console for details.');
    console.log('Error in xml2json processing node:');
    console.log(o);
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(e);
  }
}

var doc = document.getElementById("doc");
var out = document.getElementById("out");

out.innerText = JSON.stringify(xml2json(doc), null, 2);
/* Let's process the whole Code Snippet #document, why not?
 * Yes, the JSON we just put in the document body and all 
 * this code is encoded in the JSON in the console.
 * In that copy you can see why the XML DOM will all be one line.
 * The JSON in the console has "\n" nodes all throughout.
 */
console.log(xml2json(document));
```

```css
#doc,
#out {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="doc"><!-- The XML DOM will all be on one line --><div personality="bubbly" relevance=42>This text is valid for HTML.<span>But it probably shouldn't be siblings to an element in XML.</span></div></div>

<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score -5):

The best way to do it using server side as client side doesn't work well in all scenarios. I was trying to build online json to xml and xml to json converter using javascript and I felt almost impossible as it was not working in all scenarios. Ultimately I ended up doing it server side using Newtonsoft in ASP.MVC. Here is the online converter http://techfunda.com/Tools/XmlToJson