# Examples of good XML to JSON JavaScript Libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, jquery-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML <-> JSON conversion in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript)

I tried using:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xmlObjectifier

But it does not output JSON for me. It is still in XML. See usage:

```
var json = $.xmlToJSON(data);
console.log(json);
```

Are there any good XML to JSON libraries I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML <-> JSON conversion in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript) For additional SO results, [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+convert+xml+to+json).

Comment: title should be renamed so it is easier to search on stack overflow.

Comment: There is [comparison](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/comparejs/?q=xml2json) of some xml 2 json libraries on the basis of performance.