# Convert XML to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML file with the following content:

```
<directory>
  <app>
    <title>Carrot</title>
    <url>www.carrot.com</url>
  </app>
  <app>
    <title>Cucumber</title>
    <url>www.cucumber.com</url>
  </app>
</directory>
```

Assuming I had been able to read it and store the content as a string:

```
s = '<directory><app><title>Carrot</title><url>www.google.com</url></app><app><title>Cucumber</title><url>www.cucumber.com</url></app></directory>';
```

How do I convert it to a JavaScript object like the following?

```
{
  "directory": {
    "app": [
      { "title": "Carrot", "url": "www.carrot.com" },
      { "title": "Cucumber", "url": "www.cucumber.com" }
    ]  
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the answer to the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: Are you looking to convert it directly into a Javascript object, or do you just want a JSON string?

Answer (score 3):

I use this plugin ... http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

Its always worked a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the answer to the following question [Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript)

#### XML <-> JSON conversion in Javascript

quoted answer

> I think this is the best one: [Converting between XML and JSON](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/)
>
> Be sure to read the accompanying article on the Xml.com O'Reilly site (linked to at the >bottom). The writer goes into details of the problems with these conversions, which I think >you will find enlightening. The fact that O'Reilly is hosting the article should indicate >that Stefan's solution has merit.

Comment: +1 for "Be sure to read the accompanying article on the Xml.com O'Reilly site (linked to at the >bottom)."