# I need to parse an XML string result in a backbone app

Tags: marionette

In this application, one of the nested results of my JSON return I need is a string that looks like the following:

```
"<Money amount="25" currencyCode=""/>"
```

How would I pull out the Money amount to display in a model/collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone provides a parse method that will me called if provided at the time to fetch  http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

so in your model definition convert the xml to json and set the json values to the model

```
 var Amodel = Bakcobone.Model.extend({
     parse : function (response) {
         // here you parse your xml and once is converted to json you can set the values to the model
         return parsed response.
     }

 });
```

to parse the xml to json please taka a look a the following question.
[Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript)

Comment: Ah! I get it now, thanks! I imagine I could actually run a jQuery parseXML in the response to extract the value.