# Converting XML Object to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

I'm getting xml response from web service as follows:-

```
<ns2:errorList xmlns:ns2="http://www.abc.com/api/def/V1">
   <error code="DOMAIN_VALIDATE" path="address.zip">
     <message>invalid</message>
   </error>
   <error code="DOMAIN_VALIDATE" path="address.city">
     <message>empty</message>
   </error>
</ns2:errorList>
```

I want this to be in json format using jquery or javascript. Don't want to touch the web service for this. Please help.

Comment: 3 sec with google  : http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: And how to you imagine doing that? XML has children and attributes, JSON has only attributes (though they can be arrays).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Xml2Json](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) :

```
var xml = '<ns2:errorList xmlns:ns2="http://www.abc.com/api/def/V1"><error code="DOMAIN_VALIDATE" path="address.zip"><message>invalid</message></error><error code="DOMAIN_VALIDATE" path="address.city"><message>empty</message></error>
</ns2:errorList>';

var json = $.xml2json(xml);
```

Now `json` will contain the XML object. `json.error[0].path` will give you `address.zip`.