# How to parse XML Object in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a object called `Message_Content` which contains below **XML**

```
<CONFIRM_ABC_BA_007>
 <BSR> 
    <VERB>PROCESS</VERB>
    <NOUN>AB</NOUN> 
    <REVISION>001</REVISION>
 </BSR>
 <SENDER> 
    <LOGICALID>XYHXMK</LOGICALID>
    <COMPONENT>SCTWLI</COMPONENT>
    <TASK>AB</TASK> 
    <REFERENCEID>0000000000504205</REFERENCEID> 
    <CONFIRMATION>2</CONFIRMATION>
    <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
    <CODEPAGE>ISO 8859-1</CODEPAGE>
    <AUTHID>SAPWLI</AUTHID>
 </SENDER> 
 <DATETIME qualifier="CREATION">
    <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
    <MONTH>05</MONTH>
    <DAY>22</DAY>
    <HOUR>17</HOUR>
    <MINUTE>20</MINUTE>
    <SECOND>09</SECOND>
 </DATETIME>
 <DATAAREA>
    <CONFIRM_BOD> 
        <ACKCODE>0</ACKCODE> 
        <DESCRIPTN>Accepted</DESCRIPTN>
    </CONFIRM_BOD> 
 </DATAAREA> 
 </CONFIRM_ABC_BA_007>
```

Now, I want to parse it using Jquery in key-value pair in HTML page in `<span id="output"></span>`, for example:

> VERB : Process
>
> NOUN : AB
>
> LOGICALID : XYHXMK

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) will take an XML **string** and create an object with it. The documentation also contains some notes about accessing the resulting object.

[Another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript) references a [jQuery plugin for converting XML to JSON](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/).