# How to form this xml in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have the below xml and i need to form it in javascript,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <empNum>00206502</empNum>
        <itemlist>
            <orderid>4314</orderid>
            <transactiondttm>2014-01-15</transactiondttm>
        </itemlist>
        <itemlist>
            <orderid>413</orderid>
            <transactiondttm>2014-01-15</transactiondttm>
        </itemlist>

    </Employee>
```

and the number itemlist node has to be generated dynamically? Any idea how it can be done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: yeah you can use loops to put any number of itemlist there.

Comment: you want to read it in javscript or you want to convert it into jvascript readable form like JSON?

Answer (score 1):

To form xml dynamically :

```
<script>
// Simple helper function creates a new element from a name, so you don't have to add the brackets etc.
$.createElement = function (name) {
    return $('<' + name + ' />');
};

// JQ plugin appends a new element created from 'name' to each matched element.
$.fn.appendNewElement = function (name) {
    this.each(function (i) {
        $(this).append('<' + name + ' />');
    });
    return this;
}

/* xml root element - because html() does not include the root element and we want to 
 * include <Employee /> in the output. There may be a better way to do this.
 */
var $root = $('<XMLDocument />');

$root.append
(
    // one method of adding a basic structure
    $('<Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>').append
    (

            $('<empNum />').text('1') //pass employee no

    )

);

// get a reference to Employee
var $Employee = $root.find('Employee');

// get a reference to itemlist

// or find itemlist from the $root like this: $root.find('Employee>itemlist');
var list = { id1: 'transactiondttm1', id2: 'transactiondttm2', id3: 'transactiondttm3', id4: 'transactiondttm4' }; // array with values
$.each(list, function (a, b) {
    // create 'Alice'
    var $newitemlist = $.createElement('itemlist');
    // add 'orderid' element using standard jQuery
    $newitemlist.append($('<orderid />').text(a));
    // add 'transactiondttm' element using our helper
    $newitemlist.append($.createElement('transactiondttm').text(b));

    // add 'Alice' to <itemlist />
    $Employee.append($newitemlist);
}            
);


// display the markup as text
alert($root.html());
document.write($root.html());
</script>
```

This is how you can generate xml in javascript/jquery 
Please try this and you will see output as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<empnum>1</empnum>
<itemlist>
  <orderid>id1</orderid>
  <transactiondttm>transactiondttm1</transactiondttm>
</itemlist>
<itemlist>
  <orderid>id2</orderid>
  <transactiondttm>transactiondttm2</transactiondttm>
</itemlist>
<itemlist>
  <orderid>id3</orderid>
  <transactiondttm>transactiondttm3</transactiondttm>
</itemlist>
<itemlist>
  <orderid>id4</orderid>
  <transactiondttm>transactiondttm4</transactiondttm>
</itemlist>
</employee>
```

Hope this helps you, if Any queries feel free to ask questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Reed [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) about manipulating dom