# How to convert JSON to XML in Client side(JS or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

Is there a possibility to change JSON data to XML in client side(Java sript  or in Jquery).

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: @Daniel I have asked for the possibility in doing that with JQuery or Java script builtins. Is this broad ?

Comment: In the question the OP found 2 tools using jQuery. Isn't that useful?

Comment: I am afraid of the case handlings in this plugins, I read somewhere it doesnt work on data escape sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using JQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

You can create an empty xml document like:

`$.parseXML("<xml></xml>")` and then set properties on the document got from this.

An example to demonstrate:

```
var doc = $.parseXML("<xml/>")
var json = {key1: 1, key2: 2}
var xml = doc.getElementsByTagName("xml")[0]
var key, elem

for (key in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    elem = doc.createElement(key)
    $(elem).text(json[key])
    xml.appendChild(elem)
  }
}

console.log(xml.outerHTML) // logs <xml><key1>1</key1><key2>2</key2></xml>
```

Comment: I need to do the other way, Json to Xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse JSON and then `parseXML()` to create an empty XML structure and  `createElement()`,`createTextNode()` and `appendChild()` to append nodes to it.