# How to convert objects of array in to XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, javascript-objects

I have a data nested data structure or `JSON`, how can I convert that into an `XML` structure in Javascript.

```
[
    {"loanId" : "LA00123", "MemberId" : "MI00123"},
    {"loanId" : "LA001234", "MemberId" : "MI001234"}
]
```

Excepted result:

```
<result>
    <loanID>LA00123</loanID>
    <MemberId>MI00123</MemberId>
</result>
<result>
    <loanID>LA001234</loanID>
    <MemberId>MI001234</MemberId>
</result>
```

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694826/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-client-sidejs-or-jquery) see here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by an iteration you can preapre the XML element first and the join by empty character.

Here [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to make an iteration over the array and [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is used to concatenate the prepared XML element to final result.

```js
const data =  [{"loanId" : "LA00123", "MemberId" : "MI00123"},{"loanId" : "LA001234", "MemberId" : "MI001234"}]

const result = data.map(obj => `<result><loanID>${obj.loanId}</loanID><MemberId>${obj.MemberId}</MemberId></result>`).join('')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're converting data into XML as a string, you could perform reduce on the array:

```js
let obj = [{
    "loanId": "LA00123",
    "MemberId": "MI00123"
  },
  {
    "loanId": "LA001234",
    "MemberId": "MI001234"
  }
];

const toXml = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((result, el) => {
   return result + `<result><loadId>"${el.loanId}"</loadID><MemberId>${el.MemberId}</MemberId></result>\n`
  }, '')
}

console.log(toXml(obj));
```

---

Creating XML object (overkill):

```js
let obj = [{
    "loanId": "LA00123",
    "MemberId": "MI00123"
  },
  {
    "loanId": "LA001234",
    "MemberId": "MI001234"
  }
];

let doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "myXML");

obj.forEach(a => {
  let result = doc.createElement("result");
  Object.entries(a).forEach(b => {
    let node = doc.createElement(b[0]);
    node.append(doc.createTextNode(b[1]));
    result.append(node);
  });
  doc.documentElement.append(result);
});

console.log(new Array(...doc.documentElement.children).reduce((a, b) => a + new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(b), ''));
```