# How to set XML response into model in angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

How to set XML response into model.

This is the model class

```
export class Region {
    public regionCode : number;
    public regionName : string;
}
```

**This is how I had done with JSON data**

Component

```
typeMasterList: Region [];

this.masterDataService.typeMaster().subscribe(response => {
    this.typeMasterList = response['requests'];
});
```

**This is what I tried with XML.**

Sample request

```
<requests>
   <region>
      <regionCode>50002</regionCode>
      <regionName>STUV</regionName>
   </region>
   <region>
      <regionCode>50003</regionCode>
      <regionName>AINL</regionName>
   </region>
</requests>
```

I had added this in http get call  { responseType: 'text' }

```
this.masterDataService.typeMaster().subscribe(response => {
     console.log("key :"+data); // displays  full text.
    this.typeMasterList = response['requests']; // but this not working, as its xml response.
});
```

How can I assign the response to the array ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize XML to JavaScript/TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678534/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-javascript-typescript)