# Extracting JSON from string

Tags: javascript, json, string

I am getting a string from server and want to extract Json string from it 
here is the string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      [{"isAssigned": false,"Name": "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\XLEZ\\CLIENT","LastModified": ""},
    {"isAssigned": true,"Name": "\\mokuji.html","LastModified": "20140806 165709"},
    {"isAssigned": false,"Name": "\\result.html",{"LastModified": "20131002 235302"}]
    </string>
```

I am not being able to figure out how to do it...
Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41cfak0v/6/)

Comment: You could try [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) and then get the string `string` element in the XML.

Comment: Your example code doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: @Quentin I know its just for reference actual data has valid json but its in those xml tags i want to get rid of these tags

Comment: @AdilWaqar — If it contained valid JSON then people could fork it to test and demo code without having to fix your sample data first.

Comment: @Quentin example edited .. now it shows actual data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/) via [Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript)

I did this:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5krkbh8y/)

No error handling

```
function parseXml(xml) {
  var dom = null;
  if (window.DOMParser) {
    try {
        dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    } catch (e) {
        dom = null;
    }
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
        dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        dom.async = false;
        if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) // parse error ..

        window.alert(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText);
    } catch (e) {
        dom = null;
    }
  } else alert("cannot parse xml string!");
  return dom;
}


function extractJson() {
  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[ {"x":"y"},{"a":"b"}]</string>';
  var json = JSON.parse(parseXml(xml).firstChild.textContent);
  console.log(json)
}
```

Comment: This solution provides the best options for parsing XML in multiple browser environments, as well as the best DOM navigation practices.

Comment: I guess I should also have posted the jQuery I did not post because it was not tagged jQuery :/

Answer (score 2):

If you are not opposed to using jQuery, it handles traversing and extracting data from XML strings just as well as HTML strings.

You can pull the JSON string like so

```
    // Get JSON string out
    var extractedJson = $(jsonData).text();

    // If you need it as an object
    var extractedJsonAsObject = $.parseJSON(extractedJson);
```

Here is a working example of your Fiddle:

http://plnkr.co/edit/nfnjreyfv0adIZ6Ue1Ox?p=preview

Comment: This assumes that the XML will never contain anything other than a single element with JSON, and no whitespace. I suspect the OP's example was quite simple for the sake of brevity, and that the actual XML in the wild may be more complex.

Comment: Fair enough.  I assumed that they could pick it up from there.  CSS selectors for traversing the XML document also work the same as they do traversing HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I hear ya. I just wanted the OP to understand he may need to do a little more in case it wasn't obvious to him.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply parse the XML and get its content

```
function extractJson()
{

var jsonData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[ {'sone': 'json'},{'some': 'json2'}]</string>';
    var parser = new DOMParser();
 var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(jsonData,"text/xml");
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('string')[0].innerHTML);    
}
extractJson();
```

**Note:** Internet Explorer uses the loadXML() method to parse an XML string, while other browsers use the DOMParser object.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/naderz/ba58493c20eab112c7db2ae4aaacd776) is a GIST that does the job.

The code is in kotlin but can be easily translated into any language.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming Json doesn't contains tags, you can just replace all xml tags with empty string (ie remove them) like this:

```
function extractJson(){
    var jsonData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[ {sonejson},{some json2}]</string>';
    var extractdJson = jsonData.replace(/\<[^\>]+\>/gi,''); // extracted jason fron jsonData 
    alert(extractdJson);    
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should really avoid using anything but an actual parser to work with, and extract data from, markup.

Comment: If JSON will not contain any xml tags, then this will be more simple and fast then using a parser.

Comment: I disagree wholeheartedly. Furthermore, if your solution requires caveats and conditions to be useful, you can be sure those caveats and conditions will be violated in the wild.

Comment: The solution should be general or it's not useful yeah