# How to call .asmx web service using plain html page

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I am trying to call an asmx web service in plain html page. But not getting output. I'm not getting the exact problem. Here is my ajax code that I wrote to call that asmx web service.

```
function Getdet(Name)
        {
            alert('hellotest');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://192.168.1.20/myservice/service.asmx?HelloWorld", // add web service Name and web service Method Name
                data: "{''}",  //web Service method Parameter Name and ,user Input value which in Name Variable.
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response)
                {
                    alert('abcd1');
                    $("#spnGetdet").html(response.d); //getting the Response from JSON
                },
                failure: function (msg)
                {
                    alert(msg);
                }
        });
    }
```

Should I have to add anything in the code..?? Please let me know where I am going wrong in this above code.

Comment: Where the webservice hosted? Is it on the same domain with your html?

Answer (score 0):

ASMX pages are plain old Web Services and the output is (almost) always in **XML format**, so don't except JSON out of the box.

Plus, they don't work well on different domain call by default, you will need to ensure that the [**cross domain**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is correctly handled.

After all this is done, you will then use the call as:

```
success: function(response) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1773571/28004
    var xml = parseXml(response),
        json = xml2json(xml);

    $("#spnGetdet").html(json.d);

}
```