# how to convert XML to JSON in angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs, xml

I want to load an xml file and convert it into JSON in angularjs on the client side.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript

Comment: I think better option is to first grab `xml` on your server than convert it to `json` than response it to `angularjs`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Return the data from the API in format you require to prevent conversions (recommended).
2. Convert the XML to JSON using javascript.

For approach #2 I'll recommend you this solution http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

And please be sure to read [the article 'Converting Between XML and JSON'](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html) (by Stefan Goessner) to overview details of the problems with conversions.