# How to convert XML data object to json?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following `xml` in the `view's C#` block

```
@{

var xmlDoc = "<class Title="SOCIAL HISTORY" ID="1" ParentID="0">
  <helpNavNode Title="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION" ID="2" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Never" ID="3" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Occasionally" ID="4" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Socially" ID="5" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)" ID="6" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Is Alcoholic" ID="7" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" History of Alcoholism" ID="8" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" None" ID="26" ParentID="2" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None" />
    <helpNavNode Title="Alcoholism Screen Question" ID="39" ParentID="2">
      <helpNavNode Title=" Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? " ID="40" ParentID="39" Narrative="ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? " />
    </helpNavNode>
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="MARITAL STATUS" ID="9" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Married" ID="10" ParentID="9">
      <helpNavNode Title=" x 10 years" ID="15" ParentID="10" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years" />
    </helpNavNode>
    <helpNavNode Title=" Divorced" ID="11" ParentID="9" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Divorced" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Single" ID="12" ParentID="9" Narrative="MARITAL STATUS: Single" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="Recreational drug use" ID="13" ParentID="1" Narrative=":Recreational drug use" />
  <helpNavNode Title="OCCUPATION" ID="14" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" works for  x 27 years" ID="25" ParentID="14" Narrative="OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title=" 1 child" ID="16" ParentID="1" Narrative=": 1 child" />
  <helpNavNode Title=" 2/3/4/5/6 children" ID="17" ParentID="1" Narrative=": 2/3/4/5/6 children" />
  <helpNavNode Title="Activities" ID="18" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" walks regularly" ID="19" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: walks regularly" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" cycles for exercise" ID="20" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: cycles for exercise" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" runs 3 days/week" ID="21" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: runs 3 days/week" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" hunting and fishing" ID="22" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: hunting and fishing" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" hiking and camping" ID="23" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: hiking and camping" />
    <helpNavNode Title=" swims regularly" ID="24" ParentID="18" Narrative="Activities: swims regularly" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="Tobacco Use" ID="27" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title="Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless" ID="30" ParentID="27">
      <helpNavNode Title="10/pk year" ID="32" ParentID="30" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year" />
    </helpNavNode>
    <helpNavNode Title="Quit Date" ID="35" ParentID="27" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Quit Date" />
    <helpNavNode Title="Year Started" ID="36" ParentID="27" Narrative="Tobacco Use:Year Started" />
  </helpNavNode>
  <helpNavNode Title="SocHx  Template" ID="37" ParentID="1">
    <helpNavNode Title=" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " ID="41" ParentID="37" Narrative="SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " />
    <helpNavNode Title=" Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " ID="42" ParentID="37" Narrative="SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: " />
  </helpNavNode>
</class>";

}
```

1. How do i convert the above `xml` to json from `C#`?
2. How do i convert the above `xml` to json from `jquery`?

UPDATE

here is the  `console.log( {&quot;class&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;SOCIAL HISTORY&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Never&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Occasionally&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;4&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Socially&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;5&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Is Alcoholic&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; History of Alcoholism&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; None&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;26&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Alcoholism Screen Question&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;39&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;40&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;39&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? &quot;}}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Married&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; x 10 years&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;15&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Divorced&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Divorced&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Single&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;12&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Single&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Recreational drug use&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;13&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;:Recreational drug use&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;OCCUPATION&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;14&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; works for  x 27 years&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;25&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;14&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; 1 child&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;16&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;: 1 child&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; 2/3/4/5/6 children&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;: 2/3/4/5/6 children&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Activities&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; walks regularly&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;19&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: walks regularly&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; cycles for exercise&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;20&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: cycles for exercise&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; runs 3 days/week&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;21&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: runs 3 days/week&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; hunting and fishing&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;22&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: hunting and fishing&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; hiking and camping&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;23&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: hiking and camping&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; swims regularly&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;24&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: swims regularly&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;10/pk year&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;32&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Quit Date&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;35&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Quit Date&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Year Started&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;36&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Year Started&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;41&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;42&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;}]}]}} );`

thanks

Comment: What did your try? Show us your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C# - Xml to Json**

Use [JsonNet](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) from Newtonsoft.

Example:

```
string xml = @"<person id='1'>
  <name>Alan</name>
  <url>http://www.google.com</url>
  <role>Admin1</role>
</person>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

([documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm))

**Jquery - Xml to Json**

See [Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript)

Comment: plus one - you kept it short, sharp and sweet!!

Comment: @NikolaiDante the conversion is successful but when tried to access the json object (to display the content of it) console.log(@doc) this prints the content but the console of chrome gives the following error message 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &  i have updated my orignal post wit the error msg

Comment: @NikolaiDante it complaining abut having those & signs

Comment: @zeelong its probably best to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question.

Comment: @NikolaiDante okay i will post it!

Comment: @zeelong include your current code and if possible a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NikolaiDante  i have posted it in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443466/why-after-converting-xml-to-a-json-it-displays-so-many-sign-that-gives-error