# why after converting XML to a Json it displays so many '&' sign that gives error in console.log()?

Tags: jquery, json, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this post is based on the json generated from `XML` in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442259/how-to-convert-xml-data-object-to-json) when `json` was generated it generates so many '&' sign and formatting symbols here is the generated json show on `console.log()`. the `console.log()` complains about this error. how do i fix this and remove those formatting symbols from json?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

here is the `json` printed by `console.log()`

```
console.log( {&quot;class&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;SOCIAL HISTORY&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Never&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Never&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Occasionally&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;4&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Occasionally&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Socially&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;5&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Socially&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Daily (3 beers/day) (6 pack/day)&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Is Alcoholic&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: Is Alcoholic&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; History of Alcoholism&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: History of Alcoholism&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; None&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;26&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION: None&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Alcoholism Screen Question&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;39&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;40&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;39&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION:Alcoholism Screen Question: Ever had a drinking problem? Last drink? &quot;}}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Married&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; x 10 years&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;15&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Married: x 10 years&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Divorced&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Divorced&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Single&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;12&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;MARITAL STATUS: Single&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Recreational drug use&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;13&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;:Recreational drug use&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;OCCUPATION&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;14&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; works for  x 27 years&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;25&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;14&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;OCCUPATION: works for  x 27 years&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; 1 child&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;16&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;: 1 child&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; 2/3/4/5/6 children&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;17&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;: 2/3/4/5/6 children&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Activities&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; walks regularly&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;19&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: walks regularly&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; cycles for exercise&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;20&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: cycles for exercise&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; runs 3 days/week&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;21&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: runs 3 days/week&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; hunting and fishing&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;22&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: hunting and fishing&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; hiking and camping&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;23&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: hiking and camping&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; swims regularly&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;24&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;18&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Activities: swims regularly&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;10/pk year&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;32&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;30&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Cigar, Cigarette, Pipe, Smokeless:10/pk year&quot;}},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Quit Date&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;35&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Quit Date&quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;Year Started&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;36&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;27&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;Tobacco Use:Year Started&quot;}]},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template&quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;helpNavNode&quot;:[{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;41&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;},{&quot;@Title&quot;:&quot; Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;,&quot;@ID&quot;:&quot;42&quot;,&quot;@ParentID&quot;:&quot;37&quot;,&quot;@Narrative&quot;:&quot;SocHx  Template: Living situation:  Occupation:  Tobacco:  EtOH:  Rec. drugs: &quot;}]}]}} );
```

how do i remove those @ signs and " asigns

Comment: probably because you're outputting it as html text rather than plain text. The quotes have to be there in `"` form, and the `@` symbols don't matter.

Comment: did you notice when you first placed the copy-pasted text in this post and then used SO's "comment" feature, it automatically converted each `&quot` to `"`?

Comment: @wahwahwah all i want to know is i need to traverse through each json property in it and recreate my own json do those '@'symbols and quot; effects it?

Comment: @wahwahwah how do i traverse through json object that have inner arrays like above?

Comment: @zeelong you could replace it with some kind of regexp, but that's the wrong way to fix it. Output it properly in the first place instead.