# XML string to JSON javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a xml string which i want to convert in JSON string

```
var txt = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
                 <result>
                   <info>
                      <id>1</id>
                      <type>HL</type>
                      <ven>DEMOMA</ven>
                   </info>
                   <info>
                      <id>2</id>
                      <type>HL</type>
                      <ven>DEMOMB</ven>
                   </info>
               <result>";
```

i tried to initially convert it in DOM object using parser but it throws parsing error.

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
```

i want my output json string like only by using Javascript

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","type":"HL","ven":"DEMOMA"},{"id":"2","type":"HL","ven":"DEMOMB"}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript)

Comment: i can only use Javascript. No java no Jquery :(

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript

Comment: Your parsing problem is that you forgot the `/` in closing `</result>` closing tag.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gkxucxrj/1/

Answer (score 5):

I will try to explain with an example with use `x2js.js` https://github.com/abdmob/x2js and `jquery` (and without jQuery) library.

GET XML data from the API and convert this data to JSON

With jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ip-api.com/xml',
        dataType: 'XML',
        success: function(data) {
            var xmlText = data; // XML
            var jsonObj = x2js.xml2json(xmlText); // Convert XML to JSON
            console.log(jsonObj);
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

without jQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
        xhttp.send();
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("http://ip-api.com/xml"); // XML
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var jsonObj = x2js.xml2json(xmlDoc); // Convert XML to JSON
    console.log(jsonObj);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and using the example that you gave in question. Fix closed `<result>` to `</result>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txt = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> <result> <info> <id>1</id> <type>HL</type> <ven>DEMOMA</ven> </info> <info> <id>2</id> <type>HL</type> <ven>DEMOMB</ven> </info> </result>";
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json(txt);
        console.log(jsonObj);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON

Its a very small and useful script. Usage is very easy.

Include the src

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path/xmlToJSON.js"></script>`

and enjoy! xmlToJSON is packaged as a simple module, so use it like this

```
testString = '<xml><a>It Works!</a></xml>';   // get some xml (string or document/node)
result = xmlToJSON.parseString(testString);   // parse
```

'result' is your JSON object.