# Populating a JSTree using an XML file

Tags: jquery, jstree

[image]I am trying to create my JSTree using an XML file, here is the piece of code I am using so far :

```js
$("#jsopen").jstree({  
    "xml_data" : {  
        "ajax" : {
            //"url": "jstree.xml" 
            "url": "file:///C://gexml/f1.xml"      
        },  
        "xsl" : "nest"
    },        
    "plugins" : ["themes", "xml_data", "ui","types"] 
});
```

```html
<div id="jsopen" class="jsopen"></div>
```

Comment: The major problem is because you're making an AJAX request to the local file system, which is not allowed in any browsers as a security restriction. For the request to work you need to use a webserver (either local or remote). Once you've got that setup you just need to verify the XML is in the correct format for the jsTree plugin to read

Comment: Can I use something else instead of Ajax to be able to call the local file, it is a web application and I need to give the user the possibility to open a file

Comment: AJAX is what you should be using, and will work - you just simply need to run your code on a server, not on your local file system.

Comment: I am running it on the server even tried to replace the file:///... with the link  http://@:8090/xml/pages/f1.xml still getting nothing

Comment: In that case check the console for errors.

Comment: console.error(); gives me nothing to output

Comment: No I mean the actual console, press F12 to see it

Comment: using Firebug I inserted the screenshot on the question

Comment: What version of JStree are you using? I don't think the current version supports XML data any longer. If you have to start with XML data, you might want to just use another plugin to convert it to JSON data, which will then work with JStree. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript