# node.js convert xml to json object and convert back to xml

Tags: json, node.js, xml

I want to edit an xml data using node.js and angular.js. After converting xml to json, i want to do some changes and save it back to xml file. It needs to preserve the order of child elements and handle special characters like `&quot;` etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js) package.

Comment: I tried but it changes orders of child elements and does not handle special characters like &quote; etc

Comment: Shouldn't that then be part of your question?

Comment: OK, that hasn't been an issue for me. I suggest adding the requirements to the original question. You can also take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1773550/8824227

Comment: In general, when asking questions on SO you should explain the steps you took to solve the problem and why they didn't work.  That helps us a lot to answer your question.

Comment: So how did you invoke it? xml-js has two modes, compact and non-compact: which did you use?