# Convert XML to Json in angular4.0?

Tags: json, xml, angular, data-conversion

My XML

```
<list table='DDFieldList' id='59' used='true' type='list'>
    <item>
        <label>Please select</label>
        <data>0</data>
        <index>0</index>
        <itemId>0</itemId>
        <parentIndexId />
        <excludeSection />
    </item>
```

I want format like this

```
{
  "list": {
    "-table": "DDFieldList",
    "-id": "59",
    "-used": "true",
    "-type": "list",
    "item": [
      {
        "label": "Please select",
        "data": "0",
        "index": "0",
        "itemId": "0"
      }];
```

and Try to convert it to JSON how is it possible in angular4.0

Comment: Angular doesn't provide anything, but if you find a solution for how to do it in JavaScript or TypeScript, it will work in Angular

Comment: ok so how it will work in typescript

Comment: I don't know, but I know you shouldn't limit yourself to searching for an Angular solution.

Comment: Did you see this this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)** module to get comprehensive conversion from Xml to Json and wise versa.

**Module:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js

**Install:**

```
npm install --save xml-js
```

**Usage:**

```
    import { xml2json } from 'xml-js';

getItemTo(){
    var xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><list table='DDFieldList' id='59' used='true' type='list'>
    <item>
        <label>Please select</label>
        <data>0</data>
        <index>0</index>
        <itemId>0</itemId>
        <parentIndexId />
        <excludeSection />
    </item></list>`;

    var result1 = xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
    var result2 = xml2json(xml, {compact: false, spaces: 4});
    console.log(result1, '\n', result2);

return result1.list;

}
```