# Creating XML and XSL for getting JSON output

Tags: json, xml, http, xslt

What XML and XSL can I use to get the below JSON response?
I have the below output JSON that I need to get when I do XSL transformation on an XML. How can I do this?

XML:

```
<projectcontrol>
   <UPLOAD_PROJECT_CONTROL_DATA_Input>
      <InputParameters>
         <P_PROJECT_CONTROL_DATA>
            <FILE_CATEGORY>GR-01</FILE_CATEGORY>
            <PROJECT_CONTROL_TABLE>
               <PROJECT_CONTROL_TABLE_ITEM>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>4</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>4836173356</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>28833</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>2</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>2122068884</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>028834</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>2</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>2450000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>028835</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>60000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>020160</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>2</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>1438474974</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>020162</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>654000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>?????? ?????? ??? ????? ??? ???</PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>Mekeinerer</PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>NEW001</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>400000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>020164</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>200000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>20165</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>2</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>717725054</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>020166</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>450050000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>029023</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>700000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>   ????? ????? ?????? ????? ???????</PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>cvcvcvc</PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>NEW002</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>600000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>?????? ??? ???? ????? </PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>adssderer</PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>NEW003</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>100000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>????? ?????? ??????? ?????? ??????</PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>asdsaderer</PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>NEW004</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primary Routes</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>330000000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>?????? ???? ?????? ??? ????? ??????? ???? ?????? ??? ???? ?????????? </PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>asdasdsa</PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>NEW005</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primasdaaass</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>1</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>11294687884</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>023005</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
                  <element>
                     <BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>Primasd</BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME>
                     <BUDGET_NUMBER>1440913</BUDGET_NUMBER>
                     <COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <COST_CENTER_NUMBER>140000</COST_CENTER_NUMBER>
                     <MOF_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <MOF_CODE>11320</MOF_CODE>
                     <MOF_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>6</NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS>
                     <PLANNED_COST>387161000</PLANNED_COST>
                     <PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME />
                     <PROVISION_NUMBER>102011</PROVISION_NUMBER>
                  </element>
               </PROJECT_CONTROL_TABLE_ITEM>
            </PROJECT_CONTROL_TABLE>
         </P_PROJECT_CONTROL_DATA>
      </InputParameters>
      <RESTHeader>
         <NLSLanguage>AMERICAN</NLSLanguage>
         <Org_Id>101</Org_Id>
         <RespApplication>FND</RespApplication>
         <Responsibility>FND_REP_APP</Responsibility>
         <SecurityGroup>STANDARD</SecurityGroup>
      </RESTHeader>
   </UPLOAD_PROJECT_CONTROL_DATA_Input>
</projectcontrol>
```

JSON :

```
{
    "UPLOAD_PROJECT_CONTROL_DATA_Input": {
    "RESTHeader": {
    "Responsibility":"FND_REP_APP",
    "RespApplication":"FND",
    "SecurityGroup":"STANDARD",
    "NLSLanguage":"AMERICAN",
    "Org_Id" :"101"
    },
    "InputParameters": {
    "P_PROJECT_CONTROL_DATA": {
    "FILE_CATEGORY":"GR-01",
    "PROJECT_CONTROL_TABLE": { "PROJECT_CONTROL_TABLE_ITEM" : [
   {
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "28833",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "4836173356",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "4"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "028834",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "2122068884",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "2"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "028835",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "2450000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "2"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "020160",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "60000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "020162",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "1438474974",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "2"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "NEW001",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Mekeinerer",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "?????? ?????? ??? ????? ??? ???",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "654000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "020164",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "400000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "20165",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "200000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "020166",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "717725054",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "2"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "029023",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "450050000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "NEW002",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "cvcvcvc",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "   ????? ????? ?????? ????? ???????",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "700000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "NEW003",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "adssderer",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "?????? ??? ???? ????? ",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "600000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "NEW004",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "asdsaderer",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "????? ?????? ??????? ?????? ??????",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "100000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primary Routes",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "NEW005",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "asdasdsa",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "?????? ???? ?????? ??? ????? ??????? ???? ?????? ??? ???? ?????????? ",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "330000000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primasdaaass",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "023005",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "11294687884",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "1"
    },
{
    "MOF_CODE" : "11320",
    "MOF_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "MOF_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "BUDGET_NUMBER" : "1440913",
    "BUDGET_ENGLISH_NAME" : "Primasd",
    "BUDGET_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_NUMBER" : "102011",
    "PROVISION_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "PROVISION_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_NUMBER" : "140000",
    "COST_CENTER_ENGLISH_NAME" : "",
    "COST_CENTER_ARABIC_NAME" : "",
    "PLANNED_COST" : "387161000",
    "NUMBER_OF_PROJECTS" : "6"
    }
    ]
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

I have tried forming the XSL but no luck so far. I was to do the below

XML---> XSLT---> Output JSON.

I'm new to these technologies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please add the input XML and the XSL you have so far. Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript