# Convert data from XML to JSON React.js

Tags: json, xml, reactjs, npm

Im trying to build an application that fetches data from an web API that returns XML. I want this data in JSON instead, but the API does not support that.

How do i fetch the data and convert it to JSON?

I tried to use xml2js and it seems to work, but i dont understand how to save it as an object so i can use it in my app.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const url = "this is where the APIurl are";

    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(body => parseString(body, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
        })

            );
}
```

result seems to return the data as json, but i cant figure out how to use the data as an object later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use an external lib to do that. A quick search in google and I found this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js.

You should also check this question: [Convert XML to JSON (and back) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript)

To store it on your app you should grab what you need from the parsed XML and put it on the state.