# Angular 7 HttpClient XML Response

Tags: xml, angular, spring, angular-httpclient

I am using angular 7 HttpClient to make a HTTP GET request from a Spring Rest Controller which is returns a XML response.

The problem I have is how can I convert XML response to a JSON object

I've tried using the below code, but it prints XML response in Text

```
const httpOptions = {
  'responseType'  : 'xml' as 'json'

};

return this.http.get(this.url+"/items/"+ID,httpOptions);
```

Comment: this thread might help you to conver xml to json : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript

Comment: use any xml2json packages.for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-xml2json