# Using Fetch to Pull SharePoint List Items

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I am trying to pull SharePoint List Data as JSON so I can populate it to a JavaScript template library.

I have used this script to test in a SharePoint Script Editor just to make sure the JSON posts to the console, and nothing is posted to the console and no errors appear.

Here is my fetch script:

```
<script>
 var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport1')/items?$select=Team,WeekOf,OffensiveReport,DefensiveReport,SpecialTeamsReport";

const getItems = () => {
  return fetch('fullUrl')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(posts => console.log(posts))
}
</script>
```

Comment: You create a function, but never call it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use return `fullUrl` as variable name

```
fetch(fullUrl)
```

You have used `fetch('fullUrl')`, which is just a string `fullUrl`.

Do also call your function `getItems();`

Your Code should look like this:

```
 var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport1')/items?$select=Team,WeekOf,OffensiveReport,DefensiveReport,SpecialTeamsReport";

const getItems = () => {
  return fetch(fullUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(posts => console.log(posts))
}

getItems();
```

Comment: It doesn't return JSON

Comment: It is XML for some reason?

Comment: XML was used initially but we work with JSON as it looks like Javascript Object. You will have to find a way to convert this XML into JSON and may be do a JSON.parse(data) to work with the data ! This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript :-)