# Build hierarchy Json format file from multiple SQL tables in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: json, xml, migration

I have 3 or more tables that related to each other that needs to create json file in hierarchy format.

I am new on this please need some idea on how? I am creating an ASP.NET MVC program using C#.

I have created a SQL query that produce XML format output, and this is what I want to be.

My SQL query:

```
Select top 10
    'Header' QHeader,Qh.*,
    (Select 'Details' QDtails,Qd.* From TBL_SOREQDTL Qd Where Qd.ReqSeqn = Qh.ReqSeqn for xml path('Details'),type) as 'Details', 
    (Select 'Charg Units' ChrgUnit,Qu.* From TBL_SOREQCHRGUNIT Qu Where Qu.ReqSeqn = Qh.ReqSeqn And Qu.UnitSeqn = Qh.UnitSeqn for xml path('Charge_Units'),type) as 'Charge_Units'
 From 
     TBL_SOREQHDR Qh 
 for xml path('PR_Header'), root('PurchaseRequest')
```

And this is the result (XML need it to Json):

```
<PurchaseRequest>
  <PR_Header>
    <QHeader>Header</QHeader>
    <ReqSeqn>1109</ReqSeqn>
    <RequestRefNo>2007NS/000008/</RequestRefNo>
    <UnitSeqn>19</UnitSeqn>
    <ChargeUnit>19</ChargeUnit>
    <InterfaceSeqn>4722</InterfaceSeqn>
    <RequestTotals>11313.00</RequestTotals>
    <RequestDate>2007-04-20T00:00:00</RequestDate>
    <RequestedBy>NERI</RequestedBy>
    <PRType>NS        </PRType>
    <Details>
      <Details>
        <ReqDtlSeqn>2470</ReqDtlSeqn>
        <ReqSeqn>1109</ReqSeqn>
        <ItemSeqn>665</ItemSeqn>
        <ReqQty>50</ReqQty>
        <ReqUnitCost>99.00</ReqUnitCost>
        <TotalIssueQty>50</TotalIssueQty>
      </Details>
      <Details>
        <ReqDtlSeqn>2471</ReqDtlSeqn>
        <ReqSeqn>1109</ReqSeqn>
        <ItemSeqn>687</ItemSeqn>
        <ReqQty>60</ReqQty>
        <ReqUnitCost>17.80</ReqUnitCost>
        <TotalIssueQty>190</TotalIssueQty>
      </Details>
    </Details>
    <Charge_Units>
      <Charge_Units>
        <ChrgUnit>Charg Units</ChrgUnit>
        <ReqSeqn>1109</ReqSeqn>
        <UnitSeqn>19</UnitSeqn>
        <ChargeAmount>11313.00</ChargeAmount>
        <RFPAmount>0.00</RFPAmount>
      </Charge_Units>
    </Charge_Units>
  </PR_Header>
</PurchaseRequest>
```

Comment: You have two choices.  Load your data into C# classes that represent the data, then simple serialise that into JSON.  Or do an xml->json conversion, eg [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861541/2181514).   Personally, I'd query the data into classes properly rather than generate XML from the DB, but if the end-goal is imply to generate JSON then that would perhaps be overkill, especially if you already have it generating xml.